# How to capture Url change on WP* Webbrowser Control

Tags: windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

How can i listen the Url changes event on a Phone browser control?
My requirement is page1.html will be loaded on browser by default. On click event of Submit button on page1.html , it will redirected internally to Page2.html with some parameters. So i want to capture those parameters . How can i do this? Is there any AddressChanged event or similar events can be added ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is events [Navigated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigated%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [Navigating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigating%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), where you can get current Uri in parameters and react accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
private void Browser_Navigated(object sender,System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            string uri = e.Uri.OriginalString;                
        }
```

By using Browser_Navigated and Browser_Navigating both events u can get the Uri of current navigation along with all its parameters.